# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de instanciar una clase en Java?

Tags: java, poo

Estoy creando una aplicación `android` con Java y siempre he instanciado una clase se la siguiente forma:

```
  Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
  pedido.setCantidad(1); // aqui le asigno los valores
```

Pero encontré que en algunas ocasiones se hace a través de un constructor:

```
  Pedido pedido = new Pedido(1);
```

¿Cuál de las dos formas es la óptima o la estándar? No me genera un error en específico, pero si uso la forma segunda ya no puedo usar la primera.

Comment: Las dos hacen exactamente lo mismo.. No hay diferencia ni siquiera de tiempos. Y si la hubiera, es totalmente despreciable...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primero, algo particular de java.

Todas nuestras clases tienen un constructor por defecto, sin parámetros. Por eso tu puedes hacer:

```
Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
```

Ahora, cuando creas uno o mas constructores parametrizados, este constructor por defecto se pierde, para poder usarlo hay que declararlo en la clase de manera explícita. Para tu ejemplo sería algo así:

```
public class Pedido {

    public Pedido() { ... }
    public Pedido(int cantidad) { ... }    

}
```

De esta manera ya puedes usar cualquiera de los dos (incluso puedes tener mas).

Ahora, para tu pregunta concreta, se me ocurre lo siguiente. En el constructor deberían estar los atributos necesarios para que el objeto pueda funcionar correctamente a la hora de ser instanciado. Imagínate que yo voy a usar tu clase Pedido. Yo no tengo que saber como funciona internamente, a mi solo debería interesarme la API pública que expones en tu clase (los métodos públicos). No debería saber nada en cuanto la inicialización del objeto. Por lo cual, para el pedido particularmente, se podría usar cualquiera de los dos constructores.

Answer (score 4):

No hay una forma "optima", "estandar" o "correcta". Todo depende del contexto o de los requerimientos que tengas.

Quizás el negocio que estás modelando no necesite que al crear un pedido se le indique, si o si, una cantidad (o cualquier otro atributo). En este caso puedes hacer uso de un constructor por defecto o sin parámetros y en el momento que necesites definir el valor del atributo se lo pasas a la instancia.

```
Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
pedido.setCantidad(1);
```

Debemos tener en cuenta que este mismo modo lo podemos usar en el caso que tengamos valores que debemos usar por defecto al instanciar la clase, puesto que dichos valores o bien los definimos en las declaraciones de los campos de la clase o en el cuerpo del constructor.

```
public class Pedido {
    private int cantidad = 1;// valor por defecto
}

public class Pedido {
    private int cantidad;

    public Pedido() {
        cantidad = 1;// valor por defecto
    }
}
```

Si por el contrario nuestro negocio nos indica que cada vez que se cree un pedido se le deben asignar una serie de valores, los cuales pueden variar con cada pedido (por poner un ejemplo), entonces quizás si sea más correcto definir un constructor que reciba esos valores.

```
public class Pedido {
    private String idProducto;
    private int cantidad;

    public Pedido(String idProducto, int cantidad) {
        this.idProducto = idProducto;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }
}
```

En el mundo del desarrollo de software tenemos, casi siempre, varias alternativas o maneras de hacer las cosas, pero la mejor siempre depende de nuestro caso en concreto. A veces lo que resulta mejor para X cosa, no lo es para otra.

Answer (score 3):

Las dos formas son correctas. Su uso depende en el problema que estés resolviendo.

Asumamos que la clase **`Pedido`** fue definido de la siguiente manera:

```
class Pedido
{
   private int cantidad;
   public void setCantidad(int cantidad)
   {
       this.cantidad = cantidad;
   }
}
```

Al momento de usar esta clase, se lo hace de la siguiente manera:

```
Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
```

Aquí se está instanciando una clase pero aún así, se ejecuta un constructor de forma implícita (nosotros no lo vemos, pero el compilador se encarga de asignarlo a la clase).

Pero, ¿qué pasaría si le agregamos un constructor que tenga sobrecarga?

Si llegamos aplicar sobrecarga a un constructor, podríamos instanciar de dos formas.

Entonces nuestra clase quedaría:

```
class Pedido
{
   private int cantidad;

   public Pedido()
   {
       cantidad = 9;
   }

   public Pedido(int cantidad)
   {
       this.cantidad = cantidad;
   }

   public void setCantidad(int cantidad)
   {
       this.cantidad = cantidad;
   }
}
```

**El modo de uso de la clase sería:**

```
Pedido pedido1 = new Pedido();
pedido1.setCantidad(10);
Pedido pedido2 = new Pedido(1);
pedido2.setCantidad(12);
```

El código de arriba compilaría porqué la clase tiene dos constructores sobrecargados, de lo contrario, daría error de compilación si solo llegara a tener uno.

Comment: Tienes un error de concepto en los dos primero trozos de código. Si se declara explícitamente un constructor en una clase, el compilador NO agregará el constructor por defecto. Por tal motivo al intentar instanciar la clase, como lo haces en el segundo trozo de código, tendrás un error de compilación puesto que no existe un constructor sin parámetros.

Comment: @E.Betanzos Daría error de compilación, si en la clase solo tuviera un constructor parametrizado, pero en el ejemplo que propuse, tengo un constructor sin parámetros y con parámetros.

Comment: No en el primer trozo, donde solo tienes uno con parámetros, y luego en el segundo llamas a uno sin parámetros, por eso el comentario.

Comment: @E.Betanzos En el primer ejemplo, no tengo ningún constructor agregado, el compilador se encarga de asignarlo implícitamente. En el segundo ejemplo, tengo dos constructores, con parámetros y sin parámetros. ¿Cuál es el problema? Si quieres puedes probar los dos ejemplos en un compilador Online de Java: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php (yo lo hice y funciona correctamente).

Comment: Oh cierto, tienes razón, es un setter xD.